# Kubernetes: best practices setting resourcequota for kube-system namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently setting up compute resourcequotas (cpu,memory requests & limits) for each of my namespaces. However, I haven't set it yet for kube-system namespace.
I observed the cpu,memory consumption of kube-system in idle mode so I thought of putting the limits to 1vCPU & 1GiB but not sure it would be enough.
what are your recommendations for setting up the compute resourequota for kube-system namespace?

thanks a lot

Comment: That depends, what kind of cluster do you have? how many pods are deployed?
Could you post the output of your `kubectl describe node`

Answer (score 0):

I advise you **not** to put any limits to kube-system namespace.

The resources consumption depends on:

- Cluster Size;
- Number of Objects;
- API Requests Load.

If you limit kube-system you can cause OOM-Killer to kill your control plane components or even delaying API requests because of insufficient CPU, causing instability when in production.